# Echarts - exclude series from tooltip

Tags: javascript, echarts

I have a simple Echarts chart and want only the blue series to be focusable (the tooltip for the green chart should never show)
The green series should only act as a visual indicator.

Currently it behaves like this:
[image: Example Echarts configuration]

I also made a small codesandbox to illustrate the problem:

[image: Edit tender-mclaren-o5zdq]